# storing or recording Graph during performance testing

Tags: performance, performance-testing, qtp

I am doing a performance testing of an application using "HP Quick Test Professional"
I am monitoring system performance using "perfmon.msc" script. I am able to view the instantaneous performance Graph in that..but for future requirements, i want to store or record that graph....so is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QTP 10 added the capability to track system resources directly in the test. This means that the data is saved in the test-run report and that you can specify that the test has failed if some resource consumption is too high.

For more details see this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IghNH6t-ems) or [this blog](http://hpqtp10.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/what-is-local-system-monitoring-in-hp.html).